# Find value in >10% of records with replicates (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have a dataset where with patient reported side effects over the course of several visits. It looks like this in R:

```
data = data.frame("patient" = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2"),
             "side.effect" = c("Headache", "Dizzy", "Headache", "Cramps", "Dizzy", "Headache"))
```

I would like to count the number of side effects that are reported by >10% of the patients, keep the side effect label for the side effects occurring for >10% of patients, and lump everything else into an other category. In the end it would look something like (but with a lot more data):

```
SideEffect  Count
Dizzy         2 
Headache      2
Other         1
```

I am having trouble calculating this because there are multiple records for the same patients. If they were no repeats I would use fct_lump from the dplyr library. Right now

My current progress:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(side) %>% 
  summarize("num.side.effect" = n_distinct(subject.ID)) %>%
  mutate("condensed.side.effects" = ifelse(num.side.effect > 50, 
          adverse.event.term, "other"))
```

Which doesn't quite do what I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: The percentage doesn't look right `data %>% group_by(side.effect) %>% group_by(Sideeffect =  replace(as.character(side.effect), n()/nrow(.) < 0.2, "Other")) %>% summarise(Count = n_distinct(patient))`

Answer (score 1):

We can change all other elements that doesn't satisfy the condition to 'Other' and get the `n_distinct` of 'patient'

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(side.effect) %>% 
   group_by(Sideeffect =  replace(as.character(side.effect),
         n()/nrow(.) < 0.2, "Other")) %>% 
   summarise(Count = n_distinct(patient))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Sideeffect Count
#  <chr>       <int>
#1 Dizzy           2
#2 Headache        2
#3 Other           1
```